# NGINX 502 Error on specific page paths

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I've utilized [Nginx 404 Not Found when entering a specific url path](https://serverfault.com/questions/1106010/nginx-404-not-found-when-entering-a-specific-url-path/1106018#1106018?newreg=66542f45e8c44de3bdadf7c0148c90f5) to help be fix a 404 error that has been occuring when I copy any specific page path of my site into the search bar ( ie "example.com/hello" instead of "example.com"). There is no trouble reaching these paths through the initial homepage navbar itself. It also sends 502 error whenever the page is refreshed.

I am using nginx 1.18.0 ubuntu server on a digitalocean droplet. My nginx.conf under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled follows the exact solution as shown in the link above.

Anyone know what's up?